# Can't boot Ubuntu after installing Mint

Tags: boot, mint

Just installed Mint and Ubuntu won't boot. It hangs after "Checking battery"; also, I can drop to shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and access the system from the command line. What might be the problem?

Comment: Still haven't gotten any attention. Uhhhh.

Comment: At a guess, when you drop to shell, enter startx

Comment: Tried it, hangs the same way. I was reading around, and found out that if you don't have enough space on the Ubuntu partition, it might prevent the system from booting. I don't know though, I have around 1Gb. I've tried to add more space with GPartition but there's no option for merging partitions.

Comment: I would be ok if I could just extract my files from the partition too, but I encrypted my home directory and can't access it from Mint or the Ubuntu shell because I've lost my passphrase.

Comment: Did you try removing your battery? I often find that when a problem makes no sense, going back to your basic assumptions of what is wrong often results in a solution.

Answer (score 0):

are both of you operation system have same cpu architecture ? I mean are both of them 32 bit or 64 bit ? if one of them is 64 and the other is 32 you will get problem in loading . and based on my experience ubuntu 64 has a problem in loading page on some laptops it got stuck and won't do anything until you force it to shutdown and start your laptop without battery , try on plugged in mode with out battery . I have had the same problem with ubuntu and windows . let me know if it worked or not .

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://dbastreet.com/blog/?p=972) you can try killing X from the command line `killall X`. It will then restart, and you will have the login screen...

But I don't see what are the real causes of your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Just enter this in the terminal. I had the same problem.
`sudo update-grub`